# Convergence Spaces in Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, category-theory, soft-question, function-spaces

I often come across materials discussing [convergence spaces](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/convergence+space) and their relevance in various contexts. It's commonly mentioned that the existence of a *natural* convergence on the space of continuous functions (turning them into exponential objects) makes the category of these spaces a suitable environment for studying homotopy. However, I've found only a limited number of resources that actually delve into this idea (mainly [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.05601) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.13510)). As someone who doesn't engage with algebraic topology on a daily basis, this leaves me with a few questions.

1. Are there any works that effectively highlight the significance of these spaces for the *typical* algebraic topologist?
2. If not, could the issue possibly be attributed to an "excessive" use of filter-related terminology?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or references that could shed light on this matter.

Comment: In my experience, the "typical" algebraic topologist would prefer not to think about point-set details at all, but if pressed would probably gesture at Steenrod's category of compactly generated spaces, or work with simplicial sets.

Comment: In my experience too. However, given that I have some familiarity with convergence spaces, it would be nice to be able to do something that could please them.